# UDJC output using PDI

Tags: java, pentaho

I use Version 5.0.1 of Pentaho ddata integration. 
using UDJC, i manipulate data on a specific way. when i previsualise the data in UDJC step the data is correct. but if a copy the output to dummy step, the data is different from data previsualised in UDJC step.

Thanks
     the java code is the following:

```
import java.util.*;
long current_id=-1;
long tmp_id=-1;
long i=0;
Object[] out_row1 =null; 
public boolean processRow(StepMetaInterface smi, StepDataInterface sdi) throws KettleException
{
   // Read current Line
Object[] r = getRow();

if (r == null) {

    setOutputDone();
    return false;
}

String tmp = get(Fields.In, "date_mod").getString(r);
Long modif_id = get(Fields.In, "id").getInteger(r);
Long tmp_id = get(Fields.In, "items_id").getInteger(r);
Long id_search_option = get(Fields.In, "id_search_option").getInteger(r);
Long is_requester = get(Fields.In, "is_requester").getInteger(r);
String itemtype_link = get(Fields.In, "itemtype_link").getString(r);
String date_from = get(Fields.In, "date_from").getString(r);
String date_to = get(Fields.In, "date_to").getString(r);

if ( current_id==tmp_id )
{

    //No change
    if(null==tmp)  

        {
        Object[] out_row = createOutputRow(r, data.outputRowMeta.size());
        putRow(data.outputRowMeta, out_row);

        return true;
    }
        //A change Occure

    else 
    {

        //add modif            
        String tmp1 = get(Fields.In, "date_mod").getString(out_row1);
        Long modif_id1 = get(Fields.In, "id").getInteger(out_row1);
        String status=get(Fields.Out, "statusvalue").getString(out_row1);
        Long technicien=get(Fields.Out, "technicien").getInteger(out_row1);
        Long technical_group=get(Fields.Out, "technical_group").getInteger(out_row1);
        Long requester_group=get(Fields.Out, "requester_group").getInteger(out_row1);
        //New modif date
        if (modif_id1!=modif_id) 
        {                

            Object[] out_row= createOutputRow(r, data.outputRowMeta.size());
            get(Fields.Out, "date_from").setValue(out_row1,tmp);    
            out_row=out_row1;
            putRow(data.outputRowMeta, out_row);    
            date_to=get(Fields.Out, "date_from").getString(out_row1);
            get(Fields.Out, "date_to").setValue(out_row1,date_to);
            get(Fields.Out, "id").setValue(out_row1,modif_id);
        } 
        //The same modif date (Two CASE: same modif for multiple data set OR many modif 
        //for a data set
            if (id_search_option==12)//modif status
            {

                status = get(Fields.In, "old_value").getString(r);
                get(Fields.Out, "statusvalue").setValue(out_row1,status);

            } else if (itemtype_link=="User") //modif technicien
            {

                technicien = get(Fields.In, "old_value").getInteger(r);
                get(Fields.Out, "technicien").setValue(out_row1,technicien);
            } else {  //modif technical groupe

                if (is_requester==1)
                {

                    requester_group = get(Fields.In, "old_value").getInteger(r);
                    get(Fields.Out, "requester_group").setValue(out_row1,requester_group);                       
                } else {

                    technical_group = get(Fields.In, "old_value").getInteger(r);
                    get(Fields.Out, "technical_group").setValue(out_row1,technical_group);
                }
            }                
            return true;
    }
    //id change        
    } else {

    if (out_row1!=null)
    {    

        Object[] out_row = createOutputRow(r, data.outputRowMeta.size());            
        String date=get(Fields.Out, "date").getString(out_row1);
        get(Fields.Out, "date_from").setValue(out_row1,date);
        out_row=out_row1;
        putRow(data.outputRowMeta, out_row);

        out_row1=null;
    }

    current_id=tmp_id;
    if(null==tmp)  
        {

        Object[] out_row = createOutputRow(r, data.outputRowMeta.size());
        putRow(data.outputRowMeta, out_row);
        return true;
    }
        //A change Occure
    else 
    {

        Object[] out_row = createOutputRow(r, data.outputRowMeta.size());    
        get(Fields.Out, "date_from").setValue(out_row,tmp);    
        putRow(data.outputRowMeta, out_row);    

        out_row1=out_row;
        //add first modif
        if (id_search_option==12)//modif status
        {

            String status = get(Fields.In, "old_value").getString(r);
            get(Fields.Out, "statusvalue").setValue(out_row1,status);
        } else if (itemtype_link=="User") //modif technicien
            {

                Long technicien = get(Fields.In, "old_value").getInteger(r);
                get(Fields.Out, "technicien").setValue(out_row1,technicien);

        } else {  

            //modif technical or requester group

            if (is_requester==1)
            {

                Long requester_group = get(Fields.In, "old_value").getInteger(r);
                //technical_group.replaceFirst("\\D*(\\d*).*", "$1");
                get(Fields.Out, "requester_group").setValue(out_row1,requester_group);
            } else {

                Long technical_group = get(Fields.In, "old_value").getInteger(r);
                get(Fields.Out, "technical_group").setValue(out_row1,technical_group);
            }
        }
        get(Fields.Out, "date_to").setValue(out_row1,tmp);            
        return true;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I add waiting time before output rows , all data are correct. this can resolve my problem but it will lower my performance.
any suggestion.